# Certain users don't show up in the Users tab

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface, user-accounts

Playing around with the Data Explorer, I noticed two users with remarkably similar handles, *Zhak Maarli* and *zhak maar li*. Curious, I went to the [Users tab](https://english.stackexchange.com/users), searched for "zhak", and... got zero results.

The users do exist, though; they haven't been deleted in the mean time, and I even logged out to verify that I don't see them due to my 10k powers or something (which would be news to me, but who knows):

1. https://english.stackexchange.com/users/1152/zhak-maarli  (88 rep)
2. https://english.stackexchange.com/users/1507/zhak-maar-li   (21 rep)

Going by the rep, the first user should appear on [Page 75](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?page=75&tab=reputation) in the Users tab, but he doesn't:

[image: Zhak Maarli missing]

Similarly, I would expect to find the second user on [Page 79](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?page=79&tab=reputation) or [Page 80](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?page=80&tab=reputation), but he isn't there.

I did notice that both users haven't logged in for more than three months, but that can't be the reason (case in point: [Ex-user](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/96/ex-user), who's still listed on Page 1).

That leaves me wondering how many other users might be missing from the Users tab and why.

Searching the meta Meta, I have only found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26499/questions-answers-made-by-users-which-dont-seem-to-exist-in-the-users-tab), which raises more questions than it answers.

Comment: @Jasper: good catch. With [over 1900 rep](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/3444/elendilthetall) he should be on Page 1.

Comment: @Jasper: ah, that must be it. (1935 rep and still unregistered? Holy cow of Moscow!)

Comment: Elendil is a registered user now. Hooray and welcome to the site! (^_^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only registered users show up on the /users page; it's always been this way.